# Is there a size limit when query from Influxdb?

Tags: python, influxdb

I query with the following code and I am sure that there is more data but the only output I could have extend on 5 days of data. There are a lot of intra day data (every 15 minutes). Is there limit in downloading data? In which case I would need to query 1 line per day but I am not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
SELECT "account_entity" as app_vendor_id, "balance", "source", "base_ccy" as currency 
FROM "data_feeds"
WHERE "type" = 'LPACCOUNT' and ("base_ccy" = 'BCH' OR "base_ccy"='BTC' OR  "base_ccy"='ETH' 
OR "base_ccy"='ETC' OR "base_ccy"='NEO' OR "base_ccy"='QTUM' OR "base_ccy"='XRP' OR "base_ccy"='DASH' OR "base_ccy"='ENJ' OR "base_ccy"='LTC' OR "base_ccy"='MCO' OR "base_ccy"='TRX' 
OR "base_ccy"='XMR' OR "base_ccy"='USDC' OR "base_ccy"='BSV' OR "base_ccy"='BTG' OR "base_ccy"='GAS' OR "base_ccy"='UDC')
AND ("account_entity" = 'CORP')
ORDER BY "time" DESC
```

EDIT:
I found a way to reduce the array of data by using `|> hourSelection(start: 23, stop: 00, timeColumn: "time")` but I have an error when I run the code:

```
SELECT "account_entity" as app_vendor_id, "balance", "source", "base_ccy" as currency 
FROM "data_feeds"
  |> hourSelection(start: 9, stop: 17, timeColumn: "time") 
WHERE "type" = 'LPACCOUNT' and ("base_ccy" = 'BCH' OR "base_ccy"='BTC' 
OR  "base_ccy"='ETH' OR "base_ccy"='ETC' OR "base_ccy"='NEO' OR "base_ccy"='QTUM' OR "base_ccy"='XRP' OR "base_ccy"='DASH' OR "base_ccy"='ENJ' OR "base_ccy"='LTC' OR "base_ccy"='MCO' OR "base_ccy"='TRX' OR "base_ccy"='XMR' OR "base_ccy"='USDC' OR "base_ccy"='BSV' OR "base_ccy"='BTG' OR "base_ccy"='GAS' OR "base_ccy"='UDC')
AND ("account_entity" = 'CORP' OR "account_entity" = 'PTE')
ORDER BY "time" DESC
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inventory_position.py", line 66, in <module>
query_res = db_client.query(query_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 416, in query
expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 286, in request
raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found |, expected ; at line 3, char 3"}
```

Does somebody knows how to use this statement to select the hour?

EDIT 2:

I used aggregation and filter the data to 1 row per day as follow.

```
SELECT ("account_entity") as app_vendor_id, MEAN("balance") as balance, "source" as source, "base_ccy" as currency 
FROM "data_feeds" 
WHERE "type" = 'LPACCOUNT' and ("base_ccy" = 'BCH' OR "base_ccy"='BTC' 
OR  "base_ccy"='ETH' OR "base_ccy"='ETC' OR "base_ccy"='NEO' OR "base_ccy"='QTUM' OR "base_ccy"='XRP' OR "base_ccy"='DASH' OR "base_ccy"='ENJ' OR "base_ccy"='LTC' OR "base_ccy"='MCO' OR "base_ccy"='TRX' OR "base_ccy"='XMR' OR "base_ccy"='USDC' OR "base_ccy"='BSV' OR "base_ccy"='BTG' OR "base_ccy"='GAS' OR "base_ccy"='UDC')
AND ("account_entity" = 'CORP' OR "account_entity" = 'PTE')
GROUP BY time(1d), *
ORDER BY "time" DESC
```

However, I still have an error and I don't know how to solve it. I mean, it should work in a tradition sql query, as I group by...

```
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported
```

TO CONCLUDE:

There are no solution to my issue since the language does not allow to use aggregate functions AND group by the other elements listed in the same SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

"|> " is a new [Flux syntax](https://github.com/influxdata/flux), but you are using InfluxDBClient, which supports only [InfluxQL](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/) and Flux.

It is unclear what you're asking:

- if you need time condition (e.g. from - to), then use correct [time syntax](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#time-syntax) in the condition
- if you need to change data granularity, then use [GROUP BY time](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill) + appropriate aggregation function

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to change the granularity. Could you look the EDIT2 please and answer if you can?